# SOQL Query - Where Condition

Tags: soql, list, duplicate-management, search

I have below query to search for Existing Contact before creating new Contact in Salesforce. If there is a Contact with matching email and another Contact with matching Phone - results are not consistent- Sometimes it picks up with matching phone and sometimes with matching email.

How to make sure it always returns first Contact with matching email then with matching phone then by matching name and street? We have close to 450K Contacts.Will it effect Performance?

```java
    list<Contact> ExistingContact = [SELECT
            id, firstname, lastname, email, Phone, MobilePhone, MailingStreet
        FROM contact 
        WHERE (email=: con.Email AND  email !='') 
            OR (Phone=:con.Phone AND Phone !='')
            OR (MobilePhone=:con.Phone AND MobilePhone !='')
            OR (firstname =:con.FirstName AND lastname =:con.LastName AND MailingStreet =:con.street) 
        LIMIT 1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could assure, that the prevoius did not match. I mean this makes it pretty complex, but it should fullfill your needs:

```
WHERE (email = :con.Email AND  email !='') 
OR ( !(email = :con.Email AND  email !='') AND  (Phone = :con.Phone AND Phone !='') )
OR ( !(email = :con.Email AND  email !='') AND !(Phone = :con.Phone AND Phone !='') AND  (MobilePhone = :con.Phone AND MobilePhone !='') )
OR ( !(email = :con.Email AND  email !='') AND !(Phone = :con.Phone AND Phone !='') AND !(MobilePhone = :con.Phone AND MobilePhone !='') AND (firstname = :con.FirstName AND lastname = :con.LastName AND MailingStreet =:con.street) )
```

Comment: Such complex query might be killing the engine

Comment: @PranayJaiswal According to [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_soslsoql.htm) it can handle 4000 characters in the where clause, so I think it can also handle a couple expression.

Comment: But `OR` clauses torch performance and selectivity. It has nothing to do with character count.

Comment: we have close to 450K Contacts and will it effect performance ?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO use click rather than code. Go for matching rules and duplicate rules. It will provide a list of potential duplicates as well.  Refer to this [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=duplicate_prevention_map_of_tasks.htm&type=0)

Comment: Matching rules/Duplicate rules might not work for me as I need it for force.com site page.

Comment: I believe the matching rules still work on force.com site page as they are triggered on create and edit. The only difference would be that you would have to use exception handling and fetch the error in try catch block to display it. The validation rules will move to matching rules and the error handling will remain in your code. That ways you could easily change rules easily without making changes to code

Comment: I want to capture matching contact and update in salesforce.I don't want to show error to user